# Unable to Access NTFS partition

Tags: 14.04, ntfs

Previously I had installed windows 8 on my Machine along with 3 NTFS drives but now I deleted OS installed partition and install fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04. Now the problem is I can't access my remaining drives which contains important data on it. I went through some forms and found that if i want to get access to these drives need to boot system in window which resulting in again installation of windows OS but i don't want to go through such long process.Please help me to avoid this long process. Is there any another way to get  access to these drives?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you create basic partitions or dynamic partitions when you installed Windows?

Comment: do you mean they don't show up at all or you just can't mount them?

Comment: What did you try? How you can not access your partition and did you get any error? please edit your question and reply details.

Comment: Seems like a windows problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the ntfs filesystems were not unmounted by Windows and thus are marked dirty. You can clear that by using the `ntfsfix` command from the `ntfsprogs` package, which should be installed by default. It should be something like this: `sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdx1`, where sdx1 is the ntfs filesystem you need to clean.